# What is the proper syntax for an Ecto query using ilike and SQL concatenation?

Tags: sql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am attempting to make an Ecto query where I concatenate the first and last name of a given query result, then perform an ilike search using a query string. For example, I may want to search the database for all names that start with "Bob J". Currently, my code looks like this:

```
pending_result_custom_search = from result in pending_result_query,
         where: ilike(fragment("CONCAT(?, '',?)", result.first_name, result.last_name), ^query)
```

(pending_result_query is a previous query that I am composing on top of)

This approach does not work and I continue to get an empty query set. If I perform the query doing something like this

```
query = "Bob"
pending_result_custom_search = from result in pending_result_query,
         where: ilike(fragment("CONCAT(?, '',?)", "%Bob%", ""), ^query)
```

I get the correct functionality.

What is the proper syntax to get the first approach working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case I would use only `fragment`, e.g.

```
query = "%" <> "Bob" <> "%"
pending_result_custom_search = from result in pending_result_query,
         where: fragment("first_name || last_name ILIKE ?", ^query)
```

That way you can shift the focus to PostGres and use its functions instead of worrying too much about the Ecto abstractions of them.  In the above example, I used `||` to concatenate column values, but you could use PostGres' `CONCAT()` if you desired:

```
pending_result_custom_search = from result in pending_result_query,
         where: fragment("CONCAT(first_name, last_name) ILIKE ?", ^query)
```

Note that both examples here did not include a space between `first_name` and `last_name`.  Also, I added the `%` characters to the search query before binding it.

Comment: Anything else you might try here? This results in a syntax error: 

`
ERROR 42601 (syntax_error) syntax error at or near "="
(CONCAT(first_name, last_name) ILIKE = 'Alex')
`
Looks like it is not identifying the **first_name** and **last_name** fields from the actual query. For example in the same query I look at order status, and the error code shows this **t0."order_status"**, you can see that it is actually trying to access order_status from the query as opposed to what is happening with **first_name** and **last_name**

Comment: @redtomato I got my similar problem working by simply removing the `=` in the fragment string suggested by Everett. If you check the Postgres SQL syntax for that function, it's simply `<ColumnValue> ILIKE <query_string>`, just like how the `LIKE` function in standard SQL works.

Comment: I updated the answer to omit the `=` -- thanks for pointing that out.