# Is it possible to generate a query clause that combines data from multiple db columns using Ecto.Query?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a simple Postgres table that stores `first_name` and `last_name` for `Person` records. Let's say it contains the following example data:

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| John | Smith |
| Jane | Doe |
| Bob | Smith |
| Mark | Johnson |
| John | Wayne |

I also have the following function for searching up the records given a search string `name`:

```
  def search_persons_by_name(name) do
    query = "%#{name}%"

    Person
    |> where([p], ilike(p.first_name, ^query))
    |> or_where([p], ilike(p.last_name, ^query))
    |> Repo.all
  end
```

The function works as expected, in that if you search up a `name`, it'll check to see if any record's `first_name` or `last_name` matches, and return the record(s) accordingly. For example, with the search string `"john"`, the function will return the record objects for "John Smith" and "John Wayne".

The limitation I want to address is that if `name` is given as `"john smith"`, instead of returning the record for "John Smith", it produces an empty list instead. I attempted to modify the query like this:

```
  def search_persons_by_name(name) do
    query = "%#{name}%"

    Person
    |> where([p], ilike(p.first_name, ^query))
    |> or_where([p], ilike(p.last_name, ^query))
    |> or_where([p], ilike("#{p.first_name} #{p.last_name}", ^query))
    |> Repo.all
  end
```

But this would not even compile, and gives me the error:
`` ** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) \`"#{wp.first_name} #{p.last_name}"` is not a valid query expression. Only literal binaries and strings are allowed, dynamic values need to be explicitly interpolated in queries with ^ ``

I had partial success by doing the following:

```
  def search_persons_by_name(name) do
    all_names = String.split(name, " ", trim: true)

    Person
    |> where([p], p.first_name in ^all_names or p.last_name in ^all_names)
    |> Repo.all
  end
```

But the problem here is that, without utilizing `ilike`, the search string `name` must now be case-aware, which also isn't ideal.

I then tried to add a `select` clause into my query, like:

```
  def search_persons_by_name(name) do
    all_names = String.split(name, " ", trim: true) |> Enum.each(fn s -> String.downcase(s) end)

    Person
    |> select([p.first_name |> String.downcase |> selected_as(:first_name_lower)])   # only first_name just to try
    |> where([p], selected_as(:first_name_lower) in ^all_names)
    |> Repo.all
  end
```

But this also fails to compile with the error `` ** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) `String.downcase(p.first_name)` is not a valid query expression. ``.

What I've been able to gather is that the string being searched in `ilike` and `select` cannot be manipulated by elixir functions, since doing so causes a compilation error.

So I'd like some help in achieving this.

Comment: Filtering on virtual or concatenated columns is a bit tricky -- once you work out what the raw SQL query needs to look like, then you can adapt it into Ecto.
See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188292/search-on-concatenate-columns for some strategies.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It did help, as it made me realize that the SQL function `LOWER()` could potentially help, and I was able to come up with a satisfactory workaround.

Comment: For future readers, this is also a useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68818311/5437918

Answer (score 0):

I found an adequate workaround:

```
  def search_persons_by_name(name) do
    query = "%#{name}%"
    all_names = String.split(name, " ", trim: true) |> Enum.map(fn s -> String.downcase(s) end)

    Person
    |> where([p], ilike(p.first_name, ^query) or ilike(p.last_name, ^query))
    |> or_where([p], fragment("lower(?)", p.first_name) in ^all_names and fragment("lower(?)", p.last_name) in ^all_names)
    |> Repo.all
  end
```

Specifically by sending a SQL "[fragment](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-fragments)" and bypassing Ecto. This allows transformation of the column value before doing any comparisons against some other value.